Evaluation of $ \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{k^2}$
Let $\{b_n\}$ be a monotonically increasing sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$ then $ \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{k^2}$  is $??$
My attempt: Since $(b_n)$ is increasing and diverges to infinity we can apply
Stolz–Cesàro lemma. by taking $$a_n =\sum_{k=1}^{ n} \frac{b_k}{k^2} $$ then we have, $$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{k^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\frac{b_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{b_{n+1} - b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{b_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2(b_{n+1} - b_n)} $$
After this I cannot proceed further. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n = \infty \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{b_n}$ supposed to mean?

@SeverinSchraven My bad, it was a typo. Fixed it.

Write for $n\geq M$ $$ 0\leq \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k}{k^2} = \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^M \frac{b_k}{k^2} + \sum_{k=M+1}^n \frac{\left(\frac{b_k}{b_n}\right)}{k^2}\leq  \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^M \frac{b_k}{k^2} + \sum_{k=M+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}.$$ Now let first $n$ go to infinity to make the first term disappear and then take $M$ to infinity to see that the upper bound vanishes. Conclude that the limit is zero.

Thank you so much @SeverinSchraven

I suggest you write up a detailed answer with the hint I've provided.

Sure, will do @SeverinSchraven

Partial case of Kronecker's lemma: if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k=0$.
